# Input SUM depend on selectbox jquery

Tags: jquery

In the light of the code below, I want the return type to have a separate total and if the male will be the result of the total male input. In the meantime, the whole Total is going to Sales Total. Below are 2 roads as an example. There will be many more rows like this, each of which will have a type of sales / return. The following two inputs will fill up accordingly.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".track", function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(".track").each(function() {
    sum += +$(this).val();
  });
  $(".total").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<hr>
<label> Male Total: </label>
<input type="text" class="total" value="" />

<label> Female Total: </label>
<input type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to hold separate totals for male and female. Then when you loop through the inputs, get the value of the `select` before it, and use that to update the appropriate total.

```js
$(document).on("change", ".track,[name='type[]']", function() {
  const sum = {
    male: 0,
    female: 0
  };
  $(".track").each(function() {
    const type = $(this).prev().val();
    sum[type] += +$(this).val();
  });
  $("#male-total").val(sum.male);
  $("#female-total").val(sum.female);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<select name='type[]'>
  <option value="male"> Male</option>
  <option value="female"> Female</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> <br>

<hr>
<label> Male Total: </label>
<input id="male-total" type="text" class="total" value="" />

<label> Female Total: </label>
<input id="female-total" type="text" class="total" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks; But it doesn't work when I put the form on the table. What to do in this case?

      <table widht="100" border="1" >
               <tr>
                  <th> <select name='type[]'><option value='male'>Male</option><option value='female'>Female</option></select></th>
                  <th>  <input type="text" name="amount[]" class="track" value="" /> </th>
               </tr>               
         </table>

Comment: You'll need to change the DOM navigation to find the `<select>` that's associated with the `<input>`. E.g. `$(this).closest("tr").find("[name='type[]']").val()`